# Need to combine two queries into ONE

Tags: sql

I am looking two below queries should combine into one only one difference

```
SELECT count("STATUS") AS levl1,
       c.cname,
       ji.created,
       concat(p.pkey, '-', ji.issuenum) AS pkey,
       si.pname,
       ji.summary,
       cu.display_name
FROM "AO_7DEABF_STEP_RESULT" sr,
     "AO_7DEABF_TESTSTEP" ts,
     jiraissue ji,
     project p,
     cwd_user cu,
     nodeassociation na,
     component c,
     issuestatus si
WHERE sr."STATUS" = '4'
  AND sr."STEP_ID" = ts."ID"
  AND ts."ISSUE_ID" = ji.id
  AND ji.id = na.source_node_id
  AND na.sink_node_id = c.id
  AND ji.issuestatus = si.id
GROUP BY ji.summary,
         c.cname,
         ji.created,
         p.pkey,
         ji.issuenum,
         si.pname,
         cu.display_name
```

and

```
SELECT count("STATUS") AS levl2,
       c.cname,
       ji.created,
       concat(p.pkey, '-', ji.issuenum) AS pkey,
       si.pname,
       ji.summary,
       cu.display_name
FROM "AO_7DEABF_STEP_RESULT" sr,
     "AO_7DEABF_TESTSTEP" ts,
     jiraissue ji,
     project p,
     cwd_user cu,
     nodeassociation na,
     component c,
     issuestatus si
WHERE sr."STATUS" = '-1'
  AND sr."STEP_ID" = ts."ID"
  AND ts."ISSUE_ID" = ji.id
  AND ji.id = na.source_node_id
  AND na.sink_node_id = c.id
  AND ji.issuestatus = si.id
GROUP BY ji.summary,
         c.cname,
         ji.created,
         p.pkey,
         ji.issuenum,
         si.pname,
         cu.display_name
```

I want the result as below,

```
Level1 |Level2 |cname |Created    |PKEY     |Pname  |Summary |Display_name
2      |10     |Test  |2018-12-1  |K-1      |Test   |Test    |Janardhan
```

Comment: You should really stop using those ancient, fragile and outdated implicit joins in the where clause and use explicit JOIN operators (which were introduced more than 25 years ago)

Comment: But how can we able to achieve this. GIve me sample on able issue so, that next time i will follow the stuff. Great!

Comment: Something like this: http://dpaste.com/37ERTMM  - but your original are actually missing two join conditions. Something that can never happen with explicit JOIN operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
SELECT count(case when sr."STATUS" = '4' then 1 end) as levl1,
       count(case when sr."STATUS" = '-1' then 1 end) AS levl2,
       c.cname,
       ji.created,
       concat(p.pkey, '-', ji.issuenum) AS pkey,
       si.pname,
       ji.summary,
       cu.display_name
FROM "AO_7DEABF_STEP_RESULT" sr,
     "AO_7DEABF_TESTSTEP" ts,
     jiraissue ji,
     project p,
     cwd_user cu,
     nodeassociation na,
     component c,
     issuestatus si
WHERE sr."STEP_ID" = ts."ID"
  AND ts."ISSUE_ID" = ji.id
  AND ji.id = na.source_node_id
  AND na.sink_node_id = c.id
  AND ji.issuestatus = si.id
GROUP BY ji.summary,
         c.cname,
         ji.created,
         p.pkey,
         ji.issuenum,
         si.pname,
         cu.display_name;
```

Aggregate functions like `count()` ignore NULL values. The `case` expression inside the count returns `NULL` if the status does not have the desired value.

Comment: HI, your answer is fine but in "Where sr."STATUS"=3 or 4 or 5 or 6 " because I have status from -1 to 8 and it should be dynamic. I dont want to change every time in where condition status from -1 to 8 which is ever correct the value should be display.